# How to Split string Separated By Special Character

Tags: mysql, split, mariadb

I save in a field in Mysql the next String:

| Employee_ID | Department |
| --- | --- |
| 130434 | IT / Infraestructure / HW |

But I need to split in different columns separated by "/" like This:

| Employee_ID | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 130434 | IT | Infraestructure | HW |

Could you help me please?

Separated in different columns a string

Answer (score -2):

There is no SQL function for this.

If you normally want the text split up into 3 columns, do so when ingesting the data; have 3 columns in the table.

If there are exactly 3 columns in all cases, use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(...)`.